# Silverlight is calling a service that no longer exists

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis

In my silverlight application I have two wcf services, that used to be one, but due to practicallity I had to split them. On debug mode on my pc it works fine, but when I published the web site on the server (through IIS 7.0) it keeps calling the old service (wich does not exists anymore). For example: the old service was called Item, which later was made into two different services called Clients and Workshops.

Using fiddler I found that the service Item is still being called when it doesn't even exists anymore. I've tried to update, remove, add the services, change their configuration, edit the clientconfig manually as well the web.config, but nothing works. The application works fine on my pc.

Am I forgetting anything, like a file that has the old reference?? Or is this a silverlight issue? I've banging my head against the wall for the last 13 hours trying to solve this with no apparent success. I'd very much appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build service proxy instance using concrete constructor with endpoints specified, hardcoded.(for starters, to make it work, once it works you can figure out how to make it configurable if thats needed).

If you only call methods on proxies created by this constructor there is no way it will call some old service.

Also check that your deployed version is actually running in browser, could be a cached one.(but this is a long shot for sure).

Comment: Actually it was the last one you mentioned. For some reason the new site is not updating so it was running on the cached one. Only figured it out when I read your answer and immediatly after, I noticed that there was a simple visual change missing from the published site. If it wasn't for your answer it could've gotten days to figure this out. Thanks a lot